# openlayers 2 coloring a polygon layer based on a database ( postgresql ) table that is different from the attribute table of the layer

Tags: postgresql, openlayers-2, thematic-map, colormap

I have trouble coloring the polygons in my layer based on the values in a certain field in another table in my postgresql database that is different from the attribute table of the layer itself. Is there any way to do this ?

note : I am working on a decision support system that is using a key performance indicator ( KPI ) that is being calculated by means of a stored procedure and the result is received in a separate table from which I need to color my original layer that is visible to the user.

1- I am using zend framework

2- I use openlayers to render the maps from geoserver

3- My layers are published using geoserver from postgis database and I would like to use another separate table in the postgresql database in order to style one of the published layers
I think it can be done with table joins but the problem is openlayers makes layer styling by calling certain functions that deals with geoserver directly
so, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please edit your question and share what you have got so far?

Comment: I editted the question with more info

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you should be able to do a table join then simply assign a color in your polygon styling.

```
function drawPolygon(feature, olmap, hexFillColor, opacity) {

    var selected_polygon_style = {
        strokeWidth: 1,
        fillColor: hexFillColor,
        fillOpacity: opacity,
    }
    feature.style = selected_polygon_style;

    return feature;
}
```

In this instance I'm getting feature information from an ajax call then drawing and styling.

Comment: what if the join will slow down the system horribly ??